# PHP Multidimension array sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort this multidimensional array based on `[sort_order]`.

I have searched a lot of topics related with no sucess.

Can I have a little help here?

The objective is to sort the array so I can get the array on the following order:

1. `[post_images]`
2. `[localizacao]`
3. `[post_title]`
4. `[category]`

   ```
   Array
   (
       [[#taxonomy_name#]] => Array
           (    
               [post_title] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => post_title
                       [show_in_email] => 1
                       [sort_order] => 3
                       [options] => Array
                           (
                               [0] => 
                           )

                   )

               [post_images] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => post_images 
                       [is_active] => 1
                       [show_on_listing] => 1
                       [show_on_detail] => 1
                       [sort_order] => 1
                       [options] => Array
                           (
                               [0] => 
                           )

                   )

               [category] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => category
                       [is_require] => 1
                       [is_active] => 1
                       [show_on_listing] => 1
                       [show_on_detail] => 1
                       [show_in_email] => 1
                       [sort_order] => 4
                       [options] => Array
                           (
                               [0] => 
                           )

                   )

               [localizacao] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => localizacao
                       [label] => Localização
                       [htmlvar_name] => localizacao
                       [sort_order] => 2
                       [options] => Array
                           (
                               [0] => 
                           )

                   )

           )

   )
   ```

Comment: Please post the array in PHP, not the dump.

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Here is the code for test: http://pastie.org/8397931 I'm unable to put this to work. Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) useful, which allows you to sort with a callback function like so:

```
// The function which will do your comparisons:
function sortOrderCompare ($a, $b) {
    $aOrder = $a['sort_order'];
    $bOrder = $b['sort_order'];

    if ($aOrder == $bOrder) {
        // A and B have the same order
        return 0;
    }else if ($aOrder < $bOrder) {
        //A comes before B 
        return -1;
    }else{
        // B comes before A
        return 1; 
    }

}

usort($array['[#taxonomy_name#]'], "sortOrderCompare");
```

Comment: Additional note: swap 1 and -1 to reverse the sort order.

Comment: `return $a['sort_order'] - $b['sort_order']` is enough, you don't need all the rest.

Comment: Yep that works too - I wanted to make it clear what was going on in there so it didn't look too 'magical' :P

Comment: Tks but it don't work for me. I'me testing this with this code: http://pastie.org/8397931

Comment: Your variables are a little different so try usort($array['[#taxonomy_name#]'], "sortOrderCompare"); instead :)

Comment: Now i've write error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set('display_errors', '1') so i can see all errors. Ther are one warning: Warning:  usort() [function.usort]: The argument should be an array in /home/rapha3lm/public_html/tecnicform/sort.php on line 10

TThe line 10: usort($array['#taxonomy_name#'], "sortOrderCompare");

Comment: I just gave this a try myself and it worked fine (Your test array has brackets in the index which may be where you're going wrong - $array['[#taxonomy_name#]'] rather than $array['#taxonomy_name#']) - The order is also important so I've just edited the above answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Depending on your array structure it looks like this:

```
foreach( $posts as $post=>$row )
{
    $sort_order[$post]  = $row['sort_order'];
}
array_multisort( $sort_order, SORT_ASC, $posts );
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific. Sorry i'm newbie ;)

Comment: Have you tried it with your array? And can you post your actual PHP array that way I can make sure it works with your data structure.